# save input fields status with jquery, send to db to read later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to save a snapshot of an html page.
I'm quite satisfied with what I've achieved but I cannot save the exact status of each input field. for instance if I send to the db this:

```
    data = data+"&knobs="+encodeURIComponent($('#knobs').html());
data = data+"&html="+encodeURIComponent($('#pane').html());
```

and I ask it back later with:

```
            $('#pane').html((data.html));            
        $('#knobs').html((data.knobs));
```

the input fields are not correct, they miss the value attribute and have the default value instead.
since I wouldn't like to make a variable for every damn object in the page (a lot) I'm here to ask if there's any way to have an exact snapshot of the html page.

Example:

if I send to the database the html() and an input field has "movie" as .val()
when I pull the html from the database it is:

```
<input type="text" value="default value">
```

I've tried some stupid hack but none of them did work. I'd be very glad to hear from you.

bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the whole form?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the call to `$('#knobs').html()` returns the *content inside* the matched elements as html and `$('#pane').html((data.html))` sets the html inside the element.

For input elements, you want to use the `val()` function to get and set the value, like this:

```
// Save data
data = data+"&knobs="+encodeURIComponent($('#knobs').val());
// Update input fields
$('#knobs').val((data.knobs));
```

---

As noted by **shybovycha**, you can use jQuerys `.serialize()` function for the first part, to save some time: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Ok, I'll look into serialize() I will combine the two methods together because I need to preserve some attributes as well when displaying the snapshot. regards

Comment: Yep, the `serialize()` can be used as a starting point/shortcut for form fields.